# Rewrite a specific line in a txt file

Tags: java

I was trying to rewrite a line that contains student details in a txt file. There will be a list of students' detail in the file, for example:

- Name1,10
- Name2,20
- Name3,30

I tried to rewrite Name2,20 to Name2,13 using a BufferedReader to find the line with Name2. And a BufferedWriter to replace the line with new text, but it turns out the code will write my whole txt file to null.

Here's my code:

```
String lineText;
String newLine = "Name,age";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path,false));
        while ((lineText = br.readLine()) != null){
             System.out.println(">" + lineText);
            String studentData[] = lineText.split(",");
            if(studentData[0].equals(Name2)){
                bw.write(newLine);
            }
            System.out.println(lineText);
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to rewrite a specific line in txt file?

Comment: The only way (well, not strictly speaking, but realistically) to change the middle of a text file is to rewrite the entire file. But you need to write to _another_ location and then copy that back over the original file when you're done.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: The old and new line have the same length? If not, you'll have to rewrite the whole file

Comment: To rewrite the whole file does that means I need to create a new file?

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to read the entire file, and store it in a variable. Replacing the line in question while reading the current file.

Something like:

```
String lineText;
String newLine = "Name,age";
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path,false));
    String currentFileContents = "";
    while ((lineText = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(">" + lineText);
        String studentData[] = lineText.split(",");
        if(studentData[0].equals("Name2")){
            currentFileContents += newLine;
        } else {
            currentFileContents += lineText;
        }
    }

    bw.write(currentFileContents);
    br.close();
    bw.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Reading the whole file into memory is not the answer.

Comment: Emmm it still set my whole file to null